# Setting python path

Tags: python, django, path

I have a Django app and I'm getting an error whenever I try to run my code:

```
Error: No module named django_openid
```

Let me step back a bit and tell you how I came about this:

1. I formatted my computer and completely re-installed everything -- including virtualenv, and all dependent packages (in addition to Django) required for my project based on settings in my requirements.txt folder
2. I tried doing `python manage.py syncdb` and got the error

I googled the issue, and many people say it could be a path problem.

I'm confused as to how I go about changing the path variables though, and what exactly they mean. I found some documentation, but being somewhat of a hack-ish noob, it kind of goes over my head.

So my questions are:

1. What exactly is their purpose -- and are they on a system based level based on the version of Python or are they project dependent?
2. How can I see what mine are set to currently?
3. How can I change them (ie. where is this .profile file they talk of and can I just use a text editor)

Any input you would have would be great as this one is stumping me and I just want to get back to writing code :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you *really* need to alter the path? It's always best to actually think about your reasons first. If you're only going to be running a single application on the server or you just don't care about polluting the system packages directory with potentially unnecessary packages, then put everything in the main system site-packages or dist-packages directory. Otherwise, use virtualenv.

The system-level package directory is always on the path. Virtualenv will add its site-packages directory to the path when activated, and Django will add the project directory to the path when activated. There shouldn't be a need to add anything else to the path, and really it's something you should never really have to worry about in practice.

Comment: Thanks I am using virtualenv that was what I was thinking too. But even though I am running a virtualenv, and installed Django in it, the django folder is not on the path and so it's not working.

Comment: Then something went wrong with the installation. The error is complaining about django_openid, *not* Django itself. Make sure you have actually installed django_openid (it's not part of Django by default). If you have, it most likely was installed to the system-level site packages directory. Make sure your virtualenv is activated first, and then use `pip` to install the package.

Comment: Ok thanks Chris I will look into this and let you know. I did have some issues because I tried porting over my original virtualenv before I had virtualenv installed on my clean machine and tried activating it (and installed stuff) which actually worked but when I went to starting a new django project it complained I didn't have an active virtualenv running (even though it looked like there was was one active)... So that could be the issue.

Comment: That might be your problem. Virtualenvs are specific to their environment. If you move it to a different OS or platform (32-bit versus 64-bit) the packages likely won't be recognized anymore even though they exist in the package directory. Even a different version or architecture of Python can cause problems. If you need to move a virtualenv to another server, generate a requirements file with pip, then actually create a new virtualenv on the destination and use the requirements file to install all the packages fresh there.

Comment: Ok I just discovered a strange problem. When I create a virtualenv and then try to create a new Pinax project it says to me "Could not find an activated virtualenv (required)." but my virtualenv is in fact activated. Have you seen that problem before? Something weird is happening... By the way I just updated my Mac to Mountain Lion (10.8.1)... not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: UPDATE: I think I discovered the problem. I needed to install the virtualenv wrapper. I followed the instructions here and so far, so good: http://www.jongales.com/blog/2012/07/25/fixing-virtualenv-after-installing-mountain-lion/

Comment: Thanks I owe you a beer next time you're in Toronto for the many questions you have helped me resolve.

Answer (score 6):

The `path` is just the locations in your filesystem in which python will search for the modules you are trying to import. For example, when you run `import somemodule`, Python will perform a search for `somemodule` in all the locations contained in the path (`sys.path` variable).

You should check the `path` attribute in `sys` module:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

It is just a regular list, sou you could append/remove elements from it:

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/some/module/folder/')
```

If you want to change your path for every python session you start, you should create a file to be loaded at startup, doing so:

1. Create a `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable and setting it to your startup file. E.g.: `PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/user/.pythonrc` (in a unix shell);
2. Edit the startup file so it contains the commands you want to be auto-executed when python is loaded;

An example of a `.pythonrc` could be:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/some/folder/')
```

Comment: Thanks. This is extremely helpful. However, where do I append it permanently? If I do the append steps above in the shell it resets the changes when I close the shell. Is the only way to do it with the pythonrc as you described?

Comment: Have you tried to set the PYTHONSTARTUP env variable? Notice that this variable will be lost when you close your shell (to avoid this, you should put `PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/user/.pythonrc` in your shell startup file, e.g. `~/.bashrc`).

Comment: As pointed out by @ChrisPratt, you should check why you can't import your module. Otherwise, just appending the module folder to your path could be a not-so-good solution.